# Is there a better way to merge data from separate tables

Tags: oracle, left-join, union

I do reporting out of our General Ledger which has separate tables for actual and budget amounts.  I merge data by unioning three queries together in a subquery and summing the results of the subquery.

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Test data and query are below.

`-- Create actuals table

create table actuals

(

  gl_key number not null,

  amount number not NULL

);`

`-- Create budgets table

create table budgets

(

  gl_key number not null,

  amount number not NULL

);`


`--add actuals data

INSERT INTO actuals (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300001000, 10000);

INSERT INTO actuals (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300002000, 50000);

INSERT INTO actuals (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300003000, 20000);

COMMIT;`


`--add budgets data

INSERT INTO budgets (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300001000, 7500);

INSERT INTO budgets (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300003000, 20000);

INSERT INTO budgets (gl_key, amount) VALUES (300004000, 5000);

COMMIT;`


`--merge query

WITH act_bud AS

 (SELECT act.gl_key, act.amount AS act_amount, 0 AS bud_amount

    FROM actuals act

    LEFT OUTER JOIN budgets bud

      ON act.gl_key = bud.gl_key

   WHERE bud.gl_key IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT bud.gl_key, 0 AS act_amount, bud.amount AS bud_amount

    FROM budgets bud

    LEFT OUTER JOIN actuals act

      ON bud.gl_key = act.gl_key

   WHERE act.gl_key IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT act.gl_key, act.amount AS act_amount, bud.amount AS bud_amount

    FROM actuals act

   INNER JOIN budgets bud

      ON act.gl_key = bud.gl_key)

SELECT gl_key, SUM(act_amount) AS act_amount, SUM(bud_amount) AS bud_amount

  FROM act_bud

 GROUP BY gl_key

 ORDER BY gl_key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a full outer join from actuals to budgets?

http://psoug.org/snippet/FULL-JOIN-example-and-syntax_733.htm

Comment: Very Nice!  I went from a 21 lines to 7 and only one pass of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the query much easier to manage.

`SELECT nvl(act.gl_key, bud.gl_key) AS gl_key,

       nvl(act.amount, 0) AS act_amount,

       nvl(bud.amount, 0) AS bud_amount

  FROM actuals act

  FULL JOIN budgets bud

    ON act.gl_key = bud.gl_key

ORDER BY 1`